# YouTube TV | Inquiry

Tags: youtube-api

When will YouTube tv become available on Roku? Its free and I don't understand what the problem is in regards to it not being available on the device.

Could you explain?

If its in development, when can we expect it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably has something to do with Ad revenue on YouTube side and seeing that Roku has well over 2 million users the cost of data streaming could only be replaced with monies from ad revenue or the opposite, 1 video could do 2 million views in 1 day and ad providers may go into sticker shock based on the need for rapid payouts. But don't quote me.